# pointer - Global variable value lost inside func

Tags: php

Please see the code below:

```
global $global_p, $global_var;
$global_var="lorem";
$global_p=&$global_var;

function myfunc () {
    global $global_p, $global_var;
    var_dump($global_p);
    var_dump($global_var);
}

myfunc();
```

Output:

for var_dump($global_p) - NULL

for var_dump($global_var) - string(5) "lorem"

Why var_dump($global_p) - NULL ?

How can I keep the value globally?

If I will pass $global_p as a function parameter - it works. But I need $global_p as a global var only.

Comment: Seems to work as expected: http://codepad.org/uBWUO2C8

Comment: Usually passing a variable to functions is the better way to go instead of global variables (which are usually never _required_), especially when the first one works and the second one doesn't. So why do you _need_ `$global_p` as global variable (except that it should match it's name :D)

Comment: hm.. on my server i get NULL for var_dump($global_p)... what could be wrong?

Comment: KingCrunch: i understand that, but in my case I really need it to be global var.

Comment: CoDe aDDict: this is a simplified example, in reality I use $user=& JFactory::getUser(); this is Joomla

Comment: You need to get rid of the first global keyword. You only use it within functions to reference global variables. In fact, you can get rid of the whole first line.

Comment: nickb: if I delete "global $global_p, $global_var;" I get NULL for both vars.

Comment: Then you should copy and paste the actual code you're running,  because [that code works on practically every released PHP version since 4.3.2](http://3v4l.org/aVYZA)

Comment: nickb: you are right, then it goes wrong because of joomla framework, cause I run php inside Joomla framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i am getting the right output.

> string(5) "lorem" string(5) "lorem"